# How to remove every second occurrence within a string?

Tags: php, string, replace

Basically, I have a string that I need to search through and remove every SECOND occurrence within it.

Here is what my string looks like (`$s`):

```
question1,answer1,answer2,answer3,answer4

question2,answer1,answer2,answer3,answer4

question3,answer1,answer2,answer3,answer4
```

Here is what my code currently looks like:

```
$toRemove = array("\n");
$finalString = str_replace($toRemove, "", $s);
```

As you can see, each line within my `s` string contains two `\n` between them. I would like to search through my string and only replace every SECOND `\n` so that my string ends up being:

```
question1,answer1,answer2,answer3,answer4
question2,answer1,answer2,answer3,answer4
question3,answer1,answer2,answer3,answer4
```

Is this possible? If so, how can I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your specific case, you may want to just replace two newlines with one newline:

```
$string = str_replace("\n\n", "\n", $string);
```

More complicated regex solutions could collapse any number of concurrent newlines:

```
preg_replace("/\n+/", "\n", "foo\n\nbar\n\n\n\n\nblee\nnope");
```

Comment: Ahh, so simple, yet for some reason I couldn't think of it...
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Adam's answer is correct for UNIX like systems but in Windows you can have different line endings. My Regex is a little bit rusty but I think this should work for UNIX and Windows.

`$string = preg_replace('/[\n\r]{2}/', '\n', $string);` Replace exact 2 line endings

`$string = preg_replace('/[\n\r]+/', '\n', $string);` Replace 1 or more line endings